# Raspberry Pi Python script for server IP status 200 and reporting via email if it is something other than 200 status code

Tags: python, python-requests

I am looking to create a Python script to be run by my Raspberry Pi to check for my server's IP address and verify that it is reporting a 200 code. If it isn't I would like to be notified via email. I have looked on StackOverflow and Google for something similar and I haven't had a great example to replicate.  Here is what I have found and was hoping someone smarter than me could help me piece it together.

Here is what I have for getting 200 code, but I can't seem to reverse engineer it to do a not equals to '200' and get it to run properly.  If I enter a waste that will return a code other than 200 I get a bunch of errors.

```py
import requests

while True:
    url = 'http://website'

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # found code
        print('Server is up')
        break
```

I have also found this code to send an email

```
import subprocess
import time
import smtplib
import webbrowser
import os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def email():
    email_user = "email@gmail.com"               # gmail account user name
    email_password = "password"            # gmail account password
    email_send = "email@gmail.com"     # email address to send to

    subject = "Server is Down"    # change this to change email subject line

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = email_user
    msg["To"] = email_send
    msg["Subject"] = subject

    body = ""    # change this to change email body text
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,"plain"))

    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)


    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
```

So any help would be appreciated! I will also probably insert commands to open a browser API link that will turn off, and then turn on the server automatically, but I can do that until I get the initial 200 status code stuff figured out first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is likely too broad to get a clear answer. Noone is going to write the whole program for you. Instead you probably want to ask several simpler questions, each of which solves a particular problem you are stuck on as you work through writing the project.

Comment: As an aside, your email code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: And of course, if you only have a single body part (or in this case, not even that) there is no reason to put it inside a multipart container.

Answer (score 0):

There's got to be a million ways to do this, but here are a couple suggestions.

First, you will want to `import time` and put a `time.sleep()` in your code to keep from hammering the server.  You will also need to make sure the script runs on startup.  OR, you'll want to add your script to crontab so that it runs every X minutes.

Second, what happens if the server that is checking your server goes down?  There are a lot of watchdog services out there that will take care of the heavy lifting for you, one that I like (it's free with some restrictions) is https://deadmanssnitch.com.  This will do all the emailing for you, which is pretty slick.  That will generate a "everything is OK" url for you, like this: `https://nosnch.in/abcdefg`.  Here's how I would use this:

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    url = 'http://website'

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # found code
        print('Server is up')
        requests.get('https://nosnch.in/abcdefg') # your "everything is OK" url
    else:
        print("Oh no, not again")
        # no need to do anything else here, but you could if you want to
    # regardless of whether or not things are OK, pause to avoid hammering your server
    time.sleep(60)

    # here is another snippet that may be helpful:
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"server is down with code {response.status_code}")
```